# Unbreakable block

Tags: page-breaking

I want to do something like the following in TeX:

```
\begin{nobreak}  

Text here will not split over pages, it will remain
as one continuous chunk. If there isn't enough room
for it on the current page a pagebreak will happen
before it and the whole chunk will start on the next
page.  

\end{nobreak}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

See [Preventing page breaks between lines](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk) in the TeX FAQ. Basically, you may use one of the following:

- the `samepage` environment;
- a `\parbox` or a `minipage`;
- the `\needspace` command of the [package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace) of the same name.

You may also need "to accept that not everything can be accomplished totally automatically".

Comment: Fair enough. I would have thought this was a desirable thing to have, especially for bullet lists etc. Oh well, thanks for your help.

Comment: @lockstep what controls the spacing prior to samepage environment, I am getting more vertical whitespace, is this normal?

Comment: Is there something equivalent to `samepage` but prevents column breaks in a two-column doc? (I want some chunk to stay in a single column).

Comment: \nopagebreak worked for me.™

Answer (score 52):

A `\vbox` (or `\vtop`) will never be broken across pages:

```
\vbox{%
  Text here will not split over pages, it will remain
  as one continuous chunk. If there isn't enough room
  for it on the current page a pagebreak will happen
  before it and the whole chunk will start on the next
  page.}
```

(unless you `\setbox` it, and later `\unvbox` it)

Answer (score 13):

You can also use packages to create and format the environment via options:

- package [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)
- package [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) with the option `nobreak`
- package [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Comment: Using my `adjustbox` package here would be overkill. A normal `minipage` usually does it. Of course if you want to add frames or other modifications it is the way to go.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Of course it's only useful for modifactions.

Answer (score 2):

`\minipage` works well when used in conjunction with the line width. To prevent overfull hbox's you need to use:

```latex
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
content on same page
\end{minipage}
```

The key is `\linewidth`. `\linewidth` is equivalent to the text width (`\textwidth`) when not in a list. When in a list, `\linewidth` accounts for the indentation of the list. One other item that may or may not be so obvious is you should have a blank line before the minipage block. If you don't the minipage block will become part of the text it's attached to and cause the overfull hbox. Example:

```latex
content 1

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
content on same page
\end{minipage}

content 2
```

In [How make sure two elements stay on the same page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30734/how-make-sure-two-elements-stay-on-the-same-page) the suggestion was to use \textwidth but that doesn't work when in a list.