# How to make a list of unbreakable items?

Tags: lists, page-breaking

In continuation of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block) question, I tried to make a list of items each consisting of unbreakable text. This can be done manually using minipage:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %for example
\setlength{\textheight}{7cm} %about one item fits per page
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\item\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

What I would like it to to define a list environment that is just like itemize (or whatever) only that the items are automatically inserted into a minipage as in my manual example. The solution should be robust for nested list environments, so if `\item` is to be redifined, it has to be done so in a very gentle way...not sure how. After redefining the environment itemize-block (for example) the following code should compile and not break the text in each item across pages:

```
\begin{itemize-block}
\item
\lipsum[1]
\item \begin{itemize}
\item let us make sure it compiles even with 
\item a nested list...
\end{itemize}
\item
\lipsum[2]
\end{itemize-block}
```

This can surely be done...only I have no idea how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
\newenvironment{block-itemize}{%
  \itemize
  \let\olditem\item
  \let\closepage\relax  
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{%
    \closepage\olditem[#1]\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
    \let\closepage\endminipage
  }%
}{%
  \closepage
  \enditemize
}
```

Then you write

```
\begin{block-itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{block-itemize}
```

And a short explanation: When it starts, the environment begins a regular `\itemize` and then saves the usual definition of `\item` into `\olditem`. Then `\item` is redefined so that: (1) it closes the “previous” minipage (2) it starts a regular item (using `\olditem`) and (3) it opens a new minipage. Of course, for the very first item there is no minipage to close, that's why `\closepage` is first defined as `\relax` (do nothing) but it is then redefined to `\endminipage` right after the first use of `\item`. The end of the environment simply closes both the last minipage and the itemize environment.

**Note:** Actually, I would use something like `\my@olditem` and `\my@closepage` and throw the whole definition into a style file so that I don't accidentally redefine commands from another package. But I wanted to keep the code above somewhat clean without all those `@`'s lying around.

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution. I had to adapt it a little since the minipages inhibit the inter-item spacing. But that wasn't very difficult, using an additional `\def`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove the checkmark since I was having trouble with your solution. The problem with redefining `\item` the way you do it is that it affects any nested list and causes errors when there are nested lists. I edited my Question to reflect this usecase.

Comment: As a cheap solution, how about defining a new `\Item` (or something) instead of messing with the existing `\item`?

Comment: What should one do in order have the same trick but for 'description' item? Simple reusing this code cleans term formatting of description list items (outputs as [term], instead of boldify)

Comment: @glaz666, I edited the code to take this into account. It's not a particularly elegant solution, and I haven't tested it, but I guess you could give it a try.

Comment: When I tried to use the current code for a `description`-like environment TeX Live complained about `Illegal parameter number in definition of \block-description.` Ditching the redefinition of `\item` and defining a `\myitem` outside the `newenvironment` hacked it for the time being. I don't know enough to suggest a more elegant solution. That said, it does *precisely* what I needed it to. Thanks.

Comment: @dmckee Can you please post the code you used to resolve the error in this answer?

Comment: @Devin I posted it as a separate answer.

Comment: Does not work for me, sadly. `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \block-itemize. <to be read again> 1`. Mac TeX 2017

Answer (score 2):

This is a response to a comment on [Juan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4493/327).

It's a modified version of his suggestion that works with `description` environments.

```
% ==========================================================
% Adapted from TeX.StackExchange.com user Juan A. Navarro's
% solution for itemize as seen at
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4493/327
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{%
  \closepage\item[#1]\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
  \let\closepage\endminipage%
  }
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{block-description}{%
  \description
  \let\olditem\item
  \let\closepage\relax  
  %\def\item[1][]{\myitem}[1]
}{%
  \closepage
  \enddescription
}
```

I don't like having the item definition live outside the environment like that, but the variations that I tried with it inside all failed and I don't know enough to fix it.

Application looks like

```
\begin{block-description}

\myitem[Week 1] Aug. 18--22 \\

  \begin{tabular}{lp{2.5cm}p{7.5cm}}
            & Reading & Topic and notes \\
    \hline
    Mon.    & & Intro; administriva; pretest\\
    Tue.    & \\
    Wed.    & 18.1--18.5 & Electrostatics; Coulombs law \\
    Thu.    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Activity day:}} & 
              sticky electrostatics  \\
    Fri.    &  & Electrostatic force and multiple
                 charges 
  \end{tabular}

\myitem[Week 2]  Another table for the next week 

\myitem[Week 3]  Yet another table for the third week 

\begin{block-description}
```

Each week appears in its entirety on one page or the other never broken.

---

Here's a frill that came up today: to enable real footnotes in this context use something like

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myfootnotetext{o +m}{% One optional and one long mandatory argument
  \closepage% End the current item so that we are outside of
            % minipage context
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
  {\footnotetext{#2}}
  {\footnotetext[#1]{#2}}% Call \footnotetext either with or
                         % without the optional argument
  \let\closepage\relax% Re-define \closepage so that the next
                      % \myitem won't break when it tries \closepage
}
```

which requires `\usepackage{xparse}`. Then you can issue `\footnotemark` inside an item and `\myfootnotetext` at the bottom of that item and the footnote will appear at the bottom of the page (modulo pathological cases when it can't be placed properly, of course).