# Unbreakable items that can work with enumitem?

Tags: enumitem

I am using `enumitem` for a list:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item ...
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

And I want each "item" itself not breakable across a page. I have looked at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4492/how-to-make-a-list-of-unbreakable-items), but having a hard time to adapt it to work with `enumitem` package. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps putting the item contents in a `\parbox` is sufficient.

The `\itemsep` must also be incorporated in to the `\parskip` of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newcommand\itemnobreak[1]{\item \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin}{%
  \parskip=\itemsep\relax#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1-4]
\itemnobreak{\lipsum[2-3]}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP suggested a useful alternative in a comment, but it needed tweaking to capture the proper behavior of `\item` and also to allow a `\parsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\newcommand\itemnobreak[1]{\item \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin}{%
  \parskip=\itemsep\relax#1}}
\newenvironment{block-itemize}{% 
  \itemize \let\olditem\item \let\closepage\relax \renewcommand\item[1][\relax]{% 
    \closepage%
    \ifx\relax##1\olditem\else\olditem[##1]\fi%
    \minipage[t]{\linewidth}\parskip=\parsep\relax% 
    \let\closepage\endminipage }% 
  }{% 
  \closepage \enditemize }
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{block-itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-4]
\item \lipsum[2-3]
\end{block-itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to adapt this construct instead: ```\newenvironment{block-itemize}{%
  \itemize
  \let\olditem\item
  \let\closepage\relax  
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{%
    \closepage\olditem[#1]\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
    \let\closepage\endminipage
  }%
}{%
  \closepage
  \enditemize
}``` This way, I don't have to remember the open brace and close brace

Comment: Also, not sure why you have syntax error, the actual include I use is `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`, maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: @python152 This is why it is important for the questioner to provide more than just a code snippet...a full but minimum working example.  You can't expect those who might try to help you to know all the package options available.

Comment: @python152 Try this: `\newenvironment{block-itemize}{% 
  \itemize \let\olditem\item \let\closepage\relax \renewcommand\item[1][\relax]{% 
    \closepage%
    \ifx\relax##1\olditem\else\olditem[##1]\fi%
    \minipage[t]{\linewidth}\parskip=\parsep\relax% 
    \let\closepage\endminipage }% 
  }{% 
  \closepage \enditemize }`

Comment: @python152 I have provided it as a **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.