# How to prevent a \lstinputlisting being split across pages?

Tags: listings, page-breaking, input

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/how-to-prevent-lstlisting-from-splitting-code-between-pages) shows how to prevent a long listing from being split across several pages when the code is written directly into the tex file. I want to achieve the same effect when including code in separate files using `\lstinputlisting` like so:

```
\lstinputlisting[label=lst:mylist,caption=A Caption]{code/parametrised.xml}
```

How do I modify the listing environment definition given in the above question to do so?

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
  {\minipage{\linewidth} 
   \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,frame=single,#1}}
  {\endminipage}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The question has been rephrased for clarity - The answers here relate to preventing a listing from being split across pages by ensuring it's treated like a unbreakable float. Howvever, this also means that listings longer than a page will not be paginated and will run off the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4):

declare the listing to a float, then it will be automatically be set in a box:

```
\lstinputlisting[float=h]{<file>}
```

Comment: Just checked it - this will sometimes misplace the `lstinputlisting`, namely: put it after the paragraph that is immediately after it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `\lstnewenvironment` to define a new environment, define a new environment using the regular `\newenvironment`:

```
\newenvironment{filecode}[1][]
  {\minipage{\linewidth}% \begin{filecode}[#1]
   \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,frame=single,#1}}
  {\endminipage}% \end{filecode}
```

Now you use

```
\begin{filecode}[label=lst:mylist,caption=A Caption]
  \lstinputlisting{parametrised.xml}
\end{filecode}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but the code is no longer paginated, and now runs off the page as if it were a float. Is there a way to avoid that, other than this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14522/how-to-avoid-that-listings-are-interrupted-by-floats ?

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were actually interested in a solution that typesets your code without breaking (or splitting) it. Am I understanding your request incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry I've not been clear. I have long code listings, which are split across several pages by the listings environment as desired. However, other floats are appearing in between these pages, so I end up with [code page 1of2][page of floats][code page 2of2]. I now see the question I referenced originally was talking about a different issue. Should I just mark this as solved and repost?

Comment: @danH: I do think there will be different techniques involved in (1) splitting listings across pages (without restriction); and (2) splitting listings across pages without being interrupted by a float. I suggest finishing this question off by adequately rephrasing it (so there's a clear distinction between the requirements), and then repost.

Comment: Hi, @Werner, the code in this answer is not correct, I'm not sure why you use the `newenvironment` command, I just try your answer today (I'm using TexLive 2021), it looks like the contents insides this environments get modified, especially the CRLF get deleted when ship out. So, I suggest you should modify the answer and use the new method, which is the `\lstnewenvironment` commands, thanks.