# How to prevent page breaking for lstinputlistings?

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment, page-breaking

In my pdf created from latex sources I can see that sometimes `\lstinputlisting` will have a page break in the middle just because it happened to be in the end of the page. I would like to prevent it.

The solution (not marked as accepted) from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27722/how-to-prevent-a-lstinputlisting-being-split-across-pages

is not helping since it make the listing to float.

Is there any other solution to prevent page breaking before `\lstinputlisting` ?

Comment: Werner's answer in the linked question should work. Did you try that?

Comment: @HarishKumar Oh, I didn't try his answer ... my bad ... It works as I wanted.

Comment: Please consider upvoting his answer then ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar I did :)