# Can I let a listing move up two lines without introducing a break in a paragraph?

Tags: listings, positioning, minipage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent lstlisting from splitting code between pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/how-to-prevent-lstlisting-from-splitting-code-between-pages)

I have a rather long listing on a page that has 3-4 lines on the following page. Just before the listing is one 7-line paragraph.

I'd like to **have the listing start 2cm earlier** (move it upwards) so that the whole listing fits on the page. The paragraph must then lose its last 3-4 lines to the next page -- but: **without having the paragraph justification being interrupted**.

I guess I have to introduce a sort of "minipage" around the listing or something and lat that be moved around independently from the running text -- not unlike an image. But how?

Comment: `listings` can be used as an float environment. So you have no page breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `float` option for `lstlisting` (or for `\lstset`), your listings will be treated as floating, and won't be split across pages, objects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{lstlisting}[float]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

you can use something like `float=ht` to specify the float placement. Another option would be to use `\enlargethispage*` to, in this case, enlarge the `\textheight` for the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]\enlargethispage*{3\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
f    or i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
j:=square(root(i));
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Notice, however, that this can result in the last lines of text being too close to the footer.

Comment: I will use the float. I already used up my `\enlargethispage`-space