# How do I hide page numbers when overlapped?

Tags: listings, environments, page-numbering

I'm trying to add an environment for code listings to stay on one page as described in "[How to prevent lstlisting from splitting code between pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10145/46884)".

When my listing is at the bottom of the page, the page number will appear within the environment.  How do I force the page number to display outside of the environment?

An example follows. In this case the environment takes up the entire page. If possible I would like to remove page numbers entirely when it would cause a page boundary to be reached.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines,
  backgroundcolor=\color{background},
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  commentstyle=\color{pgreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{pblue},
  stringstyle=\color{pred},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
  moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
{
  \noindent
  \minipage{\linewidth}
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,frame=single,#1}}
{\endminipage}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{code}[language=Java]
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SesSmtpCredentialGenerator {
       private static final String KEY_ENV_VARIABLE = "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"; // Put your AWS secret access key in this environment variable.
       private static final String MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail"; // Used to generate the HMAC signature. Do not modify.
       private static final byte VERSION =  0x02; // Version number. Do not modify.

       public static void main(String[] args) {

              // Get the AWS secret access key from environment variable AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.
              String key = System.getenv(KEY_ENV_VARIABLE);
              if (key == null)
              {
                 System.out.println("Error: Cannot find environment variable AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.");
                 System.exit(0);
              }

              // Create an HMAC-SHA256 key from the raw bytes of the AWS secret access key.
              SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");

              try {
                     // Get an HMAC-SHA256 Mac instance and initialize it with the AWS secret access key.
                     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                     mac.init(secretKey);

                     // Compute the HMAC signature on the input data bytes.
                     byte[] rawSignature = mac.doFinal(MESSAGE.getBytes());

                     // Prepend the version number to the signature.
                     byte[] rawSignatureWithVersion = new byte[rawSignature.length + 1];
                     byte[] versionArray = {VERSION};
                     System.arraycopy(versionArray, 0, rawSignatureWithVersion, 0, 1);
                     System.arraycopy(rawSignature, 0, rawSignatureWithVersion, 1, rawSignature.length);

                     // To get the final SMTP password, convert the HMAC signature to base 64.
                     String smtpPassword = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(rawSignatureWithVersion);
                     System.out.println(smtpPassword);
              }
              catch (Exception ex) {
                     System.out.println("Error generating SMTP password: " + ex.getMessage());
              }
       }
}
\end{code}
\caption{Java implementation of SES password algorithm\label{fig:ses-password}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer when creating a minimal working example I discovered how to correct the initial issue I was seeing and realized what my actual question was.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: @HarishKumar I know how to hide a page number on a particular page. Is there a way to detect if a page number would overlap an environment and disable it if that's the case?

Comment: If you replaced the normal page number using the everypage package you could make the page number conditional.  All you would need is a way to detect the actual bottom of the text is.