# How to avoid page breaking of a section

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

I'm writing my resumee in LaTeX and I would like to avoid page breaking in small chunks of text (namely, I detail the different tasks I performed in each project, utilized languages and platforms, and I would like those blocks to stay on the same page), I'm looking for something like

```
\begin{nopagebreak}
stuff
stuff
stuff
stuff
\end{nopagebreak}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210638/latex-suppress-page-break

Answer (score 8):

The environment is called `samepage`.

```
\begin{samepage}
  ...
\end{samepage}
```

Comment: Note: Do NOT use this to keep two section headings together. If you put a label into a section whose heading is in the samepage environment, without including the label itself in the samepage environment, references to the label will bear the number of the previous section!