# New page for chapters but not for sections

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, page-breaking, chapters

I would like my report to show the chapter headings in the next page but the sections on the same page. It is a double page report. `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}`

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Literature Review} \label{chap:litreview}
\section{Concepts} \label{sect:concepts}
\section{Academic} \label{sect:academic}
```

In the case above, Literature Review should start in a new page. However, if there is enough space, the section Concepts should start on the same page as Chapter Literature Review.

I have seen solutions based on [creating a nested environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-avoid-page-breaking-of-a-section), but it seems that it would disrupt my labeling and cross referencing.

Do you know how could I start chapters in a new page but keep section headings in the same page as the chapter heading? And how to do this without disrupting labeling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the report class; the following minimal example should work on your LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Literature Review} \label{chap:litreview}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Concepts} \label{sect:concepts}
\lipsum
\section{Academic} \label{sect:academic}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Perhaps if the above doesn't work, you're using an older version of the report class?

If the above does work, are you including external files with an `\include` command? That automatically inserts a new page.

Comment: I reproduced the example and it is exactly what I need. However, the lipsum command just introduces random Latin text. Why is your example working?

Comment: The lipsum package is a useful package for producing minimal working examples: as you said it just produces random (pseudo-)Latin text. Since this works on your system, it means the report class does what you want, and so something else you're doing in your document is causing the problem. Try paring down your document to the minimal necessary so that you still see the problem: this will help you find where the problem lies. If you can get it down to a minimal example and still can't find the problem, post a more detailed example.