# Avoid page break in theorem

Tags: page-breaking, theorems

I have a theorem which is half of it on another page, as I do for you automatically (without `\newpage`) get full theorem on the next page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{teo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

[image: here]

I have the left and I need right automatically (without `\newpage`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on [@cmhughes' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30120/avoid-page-break-in-theorem/30124#30124), and therefore technically similar, the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides a means to hook into the start and end of an environment using `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment`. As such, a similar result is obtained (without using the [`ntheorem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\AtBeginEnvironment{teo}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\AtEndEnvironment{teo}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{teo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the input, the [`theorem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/theorem) is not needed to reproduce the output. However, this may also just be due to your MWE. I would think, this is probably the best way to answer your question. However...

---

I'm more curious as to why you would want to do this. For example, you'll notice in the aforementioned example that the paragraph skips are stretched to fill the remainder of the page since the theorem overflows to the following page. This can be avoided by using something like a `\newpage`. So, in the hypothetical yet likely scenario where you have a very long theorem description, you might want to consider foregoing to flush the *entire* theorem body over to the next page. In this case I would suggest conditioning on where to break or not, based on the amount of space left on the current page. The [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) provides `\Needspace{<length>}` and issues a `\break` if the remaining open space on the page is less than `<length>`. You may use it in the following sense:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\AtBeginEnvironment{teo}{\Needspace{5\baselineskip}}% \break if fewer than 5\baselineskip is available on page

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\begin{teo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

The above code adds `\Needspace{5\baselineskip}` to the beginning of the `teo` environment (using `\AtBeginEnvironment`) which will issue a `\break` if less than `5\baselineskip` is available on the current page. If more than this length is available, no `\break` will be issued. For this example, it produces the same result. Compare that to the disastrous output generated by

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\AtBeginEnvironment{teo}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\AtEndEnvironment{teo}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{teo}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```

and you'll understand why.

Comment: Thank you for help, but how to insert \noident in theorem?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Are you saying that you have multiple paragraphs in your `teo` environment, and you want them all to have a `\noindent` indentation? That is, have `\parindent` set to `0pt`? If this is the case, you can just include `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` as part of `\AtBeginEnvironment{teo}{...}`. My MWE already has this format, hence the question.

Answer (score 7):

We can follow the answers to this post: [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

In your case, one option is to use the `ntheorem` package which provides the commands `\theoremprework` and `\theorempostwork` which allow you to insert commands before and after the definition of the theorem globally.

We can use these commands to wrap a `minipage` around your theorem, as shown below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremprework{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\theorempostwork{\end{minipage}}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{teo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```