# How to prevent page breaks in lists? ("Exam" class)

Tags: lists, page-breaking, exam

I'm using the `exam` class to prepare a test.

Unfortunately, the package allows page breaks inside the solution list of a question.
Considering this toy example:

```
\question Example of question. Choose a solution:
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice A
\choice B
\choice C
\CorrectChoice D
\end{checkboxes}
```

It could be that a `pagebreak` happens between `\choice B` and `\choice C`.
How could I prevent that?

### Update

The solution proposed by Mico works unless we want to print the solutions to the test AND the last answer of a question is a `\CorrectChoice`.

Here's a MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{checkboxes}{\par\medskip%
     \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\AtEndEnvironment{checkboxes}{%
     \end{minipage}}


\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Random text for question 1
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 2
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}
  
\question Random text for question 3
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 4
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}
    
\question Random text for question 5
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}
    
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I've solved it by following the 2nd suggestion given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block), that is, surround what you don't want to be broken by `\parbox`. (For the records, using `\samepage` didn't work.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As opposed to providing code snippets, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Will remember for the next time. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you modify the `checkboxes` environment to place them in a LaTeX `minipage` automatically, as is done in the following MWE. Note that the amount of vertical spacing introduced by the `\medskip` command can be changed, e.g., to `\smallskip` or `\bigskip`, or whatever amount you prefer.

**Addendum, posted 10/25/2011:** The OP has noted that my originally-provided answer causes a problem if the list of choices *ends* with a \CorrectChoice option. The answer below is updated to incorporate this possibility; the solution consists of adding the line

```
\if@correctchoice \endgroup \fi
```

to the code in `\AtEndEnvironment{...}`.

The full MWE is:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{checkboxes}{%
   \par\medskip\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\makeatletter
\AtEndEnvironment{checkboxes}{%
   \if@correctchoice \endgroup \fi%
   \end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question Random text for question 1.

Choose a solution: 
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice A
\choice B
\choice C
\CorrectChoice D
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Observe that this solution implements Werner's suggestion to use the commands `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` commands provided by the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: I think it is much cleaner to patch it using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) - using something like `\AtBeginEnvironment`/`\AtEndEnvironment` rather than redefining the entire environment in virtually the same way. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, @Werner, for this suggestion. I've changed my answer.

Comment: I removed the [tag:etoolbox] tag from the question again. Tags should be about the question, not about the answers. As long `etoolbox` is not requested or mentioned by the question the tag should not be added.

Comment: Well... there are some problems when there is a `\CorrectChoice` as last choice and I want to print the solution sheet. It says `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endminipage ...pagefalse \color@endgroup \egroup 
                                                  \expandafter \@iiiparbox \...
l.60 \end{checkboxes}`    But I cannot see how to modify the environment to prevent that.

Comment: Please provide a more-complete example of the problems you're encountering, say as an addendum to your original question. E.g., what other packages are you loading?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment. I've edited the questions and provided a MWE reproducing the problem.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: But this still allows page breaks between the question prompt and the list of answers.

Comment: @ChristopherBarrington-Leigh - The OP's objective, as stated, was about preventing page breaks inside the list of answers. He/she did not seem concerned about having a potential page break between the question and the list of answers.

Comment: @Mico.. Quite right! [I'm not sure whether it is inappropriate to add another answer below (which is as much of a question than an answer) on this page, or whether it should be a new question..]

Comment: @ChristopherBarrington-Leigh - I think the issue you raise is sufficiently different from one covered in this posting to warrant you posting a new question. There may also have been substantive changes in the `exam` document class in the meantime, making it worth taking a fresh look at these issues.

Comment: Thank you! Instead, I think this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120046/how-do-i-keep-questions-from-splitting-between-pages-in-exam/204863#204863 already covers it, so I've posted there and hope that topic gets reawakened. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

If you wrap `checkboxes` in a `minipage`, that will stop pagebreaks

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{checkboxes}
 \choice A
 \choice B
 \choice C
 \CorrectChoice D
 \end{checkboxes}
 \end{minipage}
```

If you would like to allow pagebreaks between some choices, but not others, you might use the `needspace` package, which would allow code such as

```
\begin{checkboxes}
  \choice A
  \needspace{2\baselineskip}
  \choice B
  \choice C
  \CorrectChoice D
 \end{checkboxes}
```

This particular example would allow a break after `choice A`, but not between `choice B` and `choice C`

Comment: It works, thanks! I voted for the other option as it saves me from modifying all environments.