# How to prevent page breaks within between a question and its answer choices in Exam class?

Tags: exam

I'd like to prevent page breaks between a question and its answer choices in the Exam class. There's a good solution to the problem of how to prevent page breaks within the answer choices [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/how-to-prevent-page-breaks-in-lists-exam-class), but that question did not address how to prevent breaks between the question and the answers.

Comment: The easy solution is to put a single minipage around both the question and the choices.  It isn't automatic, but it isn't exactly onerous either.

Comment: I managed to implement the solution sugested by @Kormylo. The following code, adapts the right margin to the available width of questions or parts:
```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    aquí las preguntas o partes
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add these lines

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{checkboxes}{\par\nopagebreak\minipage{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{checkboxes}{\endminipage}
```

to the preamble to make question and checkboxes to go together..

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{checkboxes}{\par\nopagebreak\minipage{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{checkboxes}{\endminipage}

\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{}
\textheight3.4in   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Random text for question 1
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 2
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\CorrectChoice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\choice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 3
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 4
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\question Random text for question 5
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice answer 1
\choice answer 2
\choice answer 3
\choice answer 4
\choice answer 5
\CorrectChoice answer 6
\end{checkboxes}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for the checkboxes environment. However, \question is not an environment. Is there a solution for avoiding page breaks between the question and - for example - \solutionorlines?

Answer (score 0):

Since `\question` isn't an environment, there's not a good way to insert a `\minipage` before and `\endminipage` after every question. But `\filbreak` before `\question` does a pretty good job. As [Frank Mittelbach notes on another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422573/1402), `\filbreak` inserts a low level of stretching (overcome by `\fill`) and a strong suggestion of pagebreaking. If LaTeX insists on breaking between a question stem and its options, hardcoding the `minipage` around it is still available. (Note 1)

The next challenge is that the `\question` command isn't provided at the top level of the `exam` class. It's only inside a `questions` environment. Luckily, a `\questionshook` command, expanded inside this environment, is provided. So putting this in the preamble seems to work:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\questionshook}{\preto{\question}{\filbreak}}
```

Here is a complete working example, maybe not minimal, but long enough to stretch across several pages. (Note 2)

```
\documentclass{exam}
\title{Know your US States and Capitals!}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\questionshook}{\preto{\question}{\filbreak}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question What is the capital of California?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Los Angeles
    \choice Sacramento
    \choice San Francisco
    \choice San Diego
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of Texas?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Dallas
    \choice Houston
    \choice Austin
    \choice San Antonio
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Florida?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Miami
    \choice Orlando
    \choice Jacksonville
    \choice Tallahassee
\end{choices}

\question Which city is the capital of New York?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Buffalo
    \choice Albany
    \choice New York City
    \choice Syracuse
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Nevada?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Reno
    \choice Henderson
    \choice Carson City
    \choice Las Vegas
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of Colorado?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Denver
    \choice Boulder
    \choice Colorado Springs
    \choice Aurora
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Massachusetts?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Springfield
    \choice Boston
    \choice Worcester
    \choice Cambridge
\end{choices}

\question Which city is the capital of Washington state?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Seattle
    \choice Tacoma
    \choice Spokane
    \choice Olympia
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Hawaii?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Maui
    \choice Honolulu
    \choice Kauai
    \choice Hilo
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of Ohio?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Cincinnati
    \choice Columbus
    \choice Cleveland
    \choice Dayton
\end{choices}

% Additional Questions (11-20)

\question What is the capital of Arizona?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Tucson
    \choice Mesa
    \choice Phoenix
    \choice Flagstaff
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of Pennsylvania?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Philadelphia
    \choice Pittsburgh
    \choice Allentown
    \choice Harrisburg
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Illinois?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Chicago
    \choice Springfield
    \choice Rockford
    \choice Peoria
\end{choices}

\question Which city is the capital of Oregon?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Eugene
    \choice Salem
    \choice Portland
    \choice Bend
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Tennessee?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Memphis
    \choice Knoxville
    \choice Chattanooga
    \choice Nashville
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of New Jersey?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Newark
    \choice Trenton
    \choice Jersey City
    \choice Atlantic City
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Wisconsin?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Milwaukee
    \choice Green Bay
    \choice Madison
    \choice Kenosha
\end{choices}

\question Which city is the capital of Minnesota?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Rochester
    \choice St. Paul
    \choice Duluth
    \choice Minneapolis
\end{choices}

\question What is the capital of Utah?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Salt Lake City
    \choice Provo
    \choice Ogden
    \choice St. George
\end{choices}

\question Which city serves as the capital of Maryland?
\begin{choices}
    \choice Baltimore
    \choice Annapolis
    \choice Rockville
    \choice Frederick
\end{choices}

\end{questions}    
\end{document}
```

Notes:

1. LaTeX permits you to pretend a command is an environment. `\begin{question}` starts a group and expands `\question`, and (since `\endquestion` isn't defined) `\end{question}` ends the group and does nothing else. Kind of nice if you prefer to use environments.
2. [ChatGPT knows how to use the `exam` class!](https://chat.openai.com/share/596f7b3f-d529-4d7e-8738-6504353b40a8)