# How do I prevent pagebreak in some piece of text?

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

I have quite small article section like:

```
\subsubsection Some title

some text about figure:

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image-here.png}
\end{figure}
```

I think it would be much better if all those 3 "lines" (title, text and image) will come on single page but I did not find any way to do it except inserting \pagebreak before `\subsubsection`. I thought `\nopagebreak` could solve this task but I could not get the desired effect.
Is there any other option?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is remove the `\includegraphics` from the `figure` environment, since that is floating (and doesn't remain in the place you specify generally). There is no need to place images inside a `figure` environment, unless you have a `\caption`. Even then there are ways around it.

Comment: that (without `figure`) was my initial code and the result was the same :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
\begin{samepage}
  some text about figure:
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image-here.png}
  \end{center}
\end{samepage}
```

The section should not allow breaking after it anyway.

Comment: Maybe 'subsub' (section nesting level) could play role here? Nonethless samepage works like a charm, thanks

Comment: Usually you should use `\centering` and not `center` for images. `center` adds vertical spacing before and afterwards.

Comment: @Qrilka No, every sectioning command prevents page breaking immediately after it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Well the best would probably be to use some ready made "here figure" macro which will certainly also add vertical space, as `figure` does when it is placed "here".