# Keep text together without page break

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

Hello I am trying to print this poem together on a single page except it keeps getting broken in the middle.  Is there a way for me to group it together?  I looked [here](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=872) but I was unsure of the best way to go about it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.8\textheight}% just to demonstrate the breaking; in the real world,
                        % this would be text

A poem:

To yowe that Joyntly with vndaunted paynes\newline
Vowtsafed to Chawnte to vs thease noble straynes,\newline
How mutch yowe merrytt by it, it is not sedd,\newline
But yowe haue pleased the lyving, loved the deadd,\newline
Raysede from the woambe of Earth a Ritcher myne\newline
Then Curteys Cowlde with all his Castelyne\newline
Associattes, they dydd butt dig for Gowlde,\newline
Butt yowe for Treasure mutch moare manifollde.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem (e.g. everything about bibliographies, footnotes and indexes) to get a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem? Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Comment: No problem, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I reduced your MWE further: Actually, none of the packages you listed are relevant for your problem. One thing that _is_ relevant, however, is the pagebreak. I artificially introduced that by adding vertical space above your poem.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is tough to know what people need to diagnose my problems since I just started with latex.  Cheers!

Comment: After applying the appropriate tag [tag:page-breaking], I noticed that your question has already been asked here. See the answers of that question. This one will most likely be closed soon. Make sure to check if your question has been asked already because we want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for being cooperative and understanding! You're definitely in the right place to learn a lot about LaTeX & friends, and you'll get used to the little things that are different here compared to normal forums on the Internet.

Comment: By chance, do you know how to keep a line of text together?  The solutions I have tried with the paragraph have not worked but I was wondering about another problem I am having.  Thanks

Comment: Put the words you don't want to be broken in a `\mbox{your text here won't be broken into the next line even if it extends into the margin, which will look terrible}`. If the solutions to [Unbreakable block](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471) don't help you, feel free to edit this question, specifying why they didn't help you in your situation! Similarly, feel free to ask a question about unbreakable lines (after researching if this question has been asked here already).

Answer (score 3):

This problem is discussed in the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk). Take a look there.

The first thing you could try is using the `samepage` environment.
Although, like mentioned in the FAQ, this might not work in every case, it is the most convenient way to go. Especially if the block your trying to create contains only text.

Automatically avoiding any annoyance altogether, seems not to be possible with existing solutions, if I read the FAQ correctly. What you should do is choose one solution and test whether it gives any errors in your specific use case.  I would try `samepage` first.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but I was unsure what would be the best way to do it.  (hopefully someone else has experience)  The FAQ just mentions the difficulties of the \samepage environment so I was hoping to avoid it if possible/preferable.