# How to force the text to enter into a single page

Tags: page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block)

Does it exist a command to force the text to make it enter into a single page?
I have a bullet list and for only one item it goes to the next page.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question; look at the `\enlargethispage` command.

Answer (score 5):

There is the `samepage` environment. I would try the following:

```
  \begin{samepage}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item lala
  \item lala
  \end{itemize}
  \end{samepage}
```

Maybe that's good enough for you.

In addition you can use the `enlargethispage` command. Place e. g. `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` right **before** the beginning of **your list**. I have seen poeple using `normalbaselineskip` instead of `baselineskip`. Frankly, I do not know the difference.

**EDIT:** As stated in one of the comments, there is a [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block) question with good answers.