# How to place multiple tablenotes on appropriate page with longtable?

Tags: tables, footnotes, longtable, elsarticle, threeparttable

I am trying to get footnotes (footnotes 2 and 3 in MWE) at the bottom of the table on the appropriate page with longtable. But with MWE I have provided I am able to get footnote only at the end of the table. Is it possible to get footnotes at the bottom on the appropriate page? And I also require footnotes (footnote 1 in MWE) on the header to appear at the bottom of every page.

MWE

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}



\begin{document}
% \begin{threeparttable}
% \begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for 
highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen\tnote{1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

0 & (1, 11, 13725) & (1, 12, 10980), (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
2745 & (1, 12, 10980) & (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
5490 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
8235 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
10980 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
13725\tnote{2} & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
16470 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
19215 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
21960 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
24705 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
27450 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
30195 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
32940 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
35685 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
38430 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
41175 & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
43920 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
46665 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
49410 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
52155 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
54900 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
57645 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
60390 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
63135 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
65880 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
68625 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
71370 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
74115 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
76860 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
79605 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
82350 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
85095\tnote{2} & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
87840 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
90585 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
93330 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
96075 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
98820 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
101565 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
104310 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
107055 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
109800 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
112545 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
115290 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
118035 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
120780 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
123525 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
126270 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
129015 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
131760 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
134505 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
137250 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
139995\tnote{3} & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
142740 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
145485 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
148230 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
150975 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
153720 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
156465 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
159210 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
161955 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
164700 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
\end{longtable}
% \end{center}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1]{Footnote 1}
\item[2]{Footnote 2}
\item[3]{Footnote 3}
\end{tablenotes}
% \end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you at least be using `threeparttablex` which extends `threeparttable` to work with `longtable`. The original package can't be used with `longtable` as I understand it.

Comment: It won't let you add them per page, though. To do that you would need to rewrite `longtable`s internals, I think. You could certainly fake a note in the table footer on every page, though.

Comment: But you should not, probably, use `threeparttable` at all with this class. If you are submitting to a journal which uses this class, follow their instructions. If not, there's no reason to use this class and it would be better to use a more flexible standard class.

Comment: This class has to be used.

Comment: In that case, for journal submission, you should follow their instructions for presenting tables and use any macros they provide. You shouldn't use e.g. `threeparttable` unless you know its use is approved by the journal.

Comment: @cfr Are there any other class with which the footnotes placed on the appropriate page?

Comment: As I say, as far as I know, you'd have to rewrite `longtable`s internals i.e. write a new package. It has nothing to do with the class. It is just how the package works.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102394/placement-of-tablenotes-in-longtable-with-threeparttablex?rq=1. It does not answer your question, but it does show you what you want to be doing if you want to combine `threeparttable` with `longtable` i.e. use of `threeparttablex`. So it should at least improve things a bit.