# Theorem header and *all* content on separate pages

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, theorems

I have in my paper a theorem-like environment which consists only of an enumerated list. It looks bad if I just type it in vanilla, so I add a $\,$ before the enumerate (see also [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/enumerate-alignment-problem-in-theorem-environment)).

The problem is, it so happens that the theorem header is printed on one page, while the first item is printed on another, which is clearly awful.

I don't mind *some* items being printed on a page separate from the header (so [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234119/keep-theorem-content-on-the-same-page) is not a solution to my problem), but if *all* the content is separated from the header, this is really bad, in my opinion.

Is there a solution, preferably one that will not cause great problems when the theorem shifts slightly after subsequent changes in the surrounding text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}



\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\

    %%%Looks bad!!!
    \begin{thm}$\,$
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
            a
            \item
            b\qed
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `\needpsace` package. `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` will go to next page if there is not sufficient room for 3 lines on current page.

Comment: @PeterGrill: This looks like exactly what I need. Would you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: A minor issue is that the command itself does seem to take a minimal amount of vertical space. But this is not that bad.

Comment: the usual suggestion for starting a list on a new line for a theorem (with `amsthm`) is to use `\leavevmode` rather than `\,`.  but there's still the danger of "breakage", so `\needspace` may still be needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: \leavevmode has the same effect. (Well, I did not check to see if the effect is *exactly* the same, but the problem persists.)

Comment: i did say that `\needspace` would still be needed.  @PeterGrill's suggestion is the real answer; i was just trying to tidy up the corners.  the problem is known -- the beginning of a list is defined to be a good place to break a page -- and is on a list of problems to be investigated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sure, thanks for the information. By the way, is there any advantage to using \leavevmode instead of $\,$?

Comment: other than `\leavevmode` is conceptually "cleaner" with respect to how the theorem environment is defined, not really.  (and, granted, "cleaner" is not easy to define; but it's what's recommended by the person who wrote the code.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Okay, thanks. I'll stick to that in the future. :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton what about changing `\@beginparpenalty`?

Comment: @touhami -- seems worth testing, but it'll take a few days before i have time.  will report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `\needpsace` package, you can apply `\needspace{3\baselineskip}` before the theorem and then TeX will go to next page if there is not sufficient room for 3 lines on current page:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-4]
    a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\

    \needspace{3\baselineskip}%
    %%%Looks good now!!!
    \begin{thm}$\,$
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
            a
            \item
            b\qed
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{thm}

\end{document}
```