# Macros that contain catcode 1 and 2

Tags: macros, catcodes

I would like to create a macro for keeping lines together. I have read [unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block) and other posts like it. What I have found to work best is the simple use of `\vbox`; A MWE is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,34}{% also works for 33
\par text line
}

\vspace{15pt}
\vbox{
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together
}

\foreach \n in {0,...,33}{
\par text line
}

\end{document}
```

The problem is my latex file is automatically generated by a separate process that I have no access to. However, there are hooks in the code like in the following example, which does not run.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\blockStart}{
\vspace{15pt}
\vbox{
}

\newcommand{\blockStop}{
}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,34}{
\par text line
}

\blockStart
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together
\blockStop

\foreach \n in {0,...,33}{
\par text line
}

\end{document}
```

My task is to define macros for `\blockStart` and `\blockStop` that make this code work like the first example. The problem is the hanging braces in the `\newcommand` lines. I am not looking for an alternative to `\vbox`; it does exactly what I want with no extra spacing issues. I am looking for a way to define these macros.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some TeX primitives (e.g., `\vbox`, `\hbox`) can be used with implicit braces: `\bgroup` and `\egroup`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\blockStart}{%
  \vspace{15pt}%
  \vbox\bgroup
}

\newcommand{\blockStop}{%
  \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,34}{
\par text line
}

\blockStart
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together
\blockStop

\foreach \n in {0,...,33}{
  \par text line
}

\end{document}
```

This is also, how environment `lrbox` works (`\hbox` + `\bgroup` and `\egroup`). However, `\bgroup` and `\egroup` cannot replace curly braces (category code tokens 1 and 2) for macro arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\blockStart}{\begin{samepage}}
\newcommand{\blockStop}{\end{samepage}}



\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,35}{
\par text line
}

\blockStart
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together\\
Keep these lines together
\blockStop

\foreach \n in {0,...,33}{
\par text line
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `samepage` has different spacing than `vbox`. Thanks, though.