# How can I enlarge a page only if I need to prevent a page break?

Tags: page-breaking

How can I tell LaTeX to enlarge a page only if there will be a page break? I don't want to have to delete the `\enlargethispage` command later on if I insert text higher up:

```
\newenvironment{stanza}
{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \begin{verse}}
{\end{verse} \end{minipage}}

...

\stanza
...
A regular army of hippopotami\\
All singing this haunting refrain:
\endstanza \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}

\nopagebreak
\emph{Chorus}
```

Currently, *Chorus* is printed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Set the `\textheight` to the maximal length that is acceptable, make sure `\raggedbottom` is active (this will give you the effect that some pages are larger than others), and take care that stuff that should appear on the same page is not split by a page break (see [Unbreakable block](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4472/110998) how to do this).

Comment: @gernot Thanks. I would accept it if you made that an answer. I'm not sure how much vertical distance `\raggedbottom` is allowed to play with when making the page break, but it doesn't seem like that matters in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but my comment is not substantial enough to be called an answer. Moreover, it may well be that there will be more contributions. It's Sunday, and your post is just 9 hours old.

Comment: You can use \smash or \raisebox to overlap the bottom of a particular page, but its a lot easier to shrink large text areas than expand small ones.