# Keep closing letter section in first page

Tags: page-breaking, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I have a *letter* which, visually and practically, will look nicer if all content, including the closing section (closing sentence + small image of a signature + name), is kept in page 1. The content, as seen in the following screenshots, is not much.

The letter is based on the following files:

- [custom_invoice_template_el.tex](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el/blob/master/custom_invoice_template_el.tex)
- [custom_invoice_mwe_el.tex](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el/blob/master/custom_invoice_mwe_el.tex)
- [custom_invoice_asymTypB_el.lco](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el/blob/master/custom_invoice_asymTypB_el.lco)

(which are based on the files at [invoice_el/tree/master/sources](https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el/tree/master/sources))

**Update**

As per one of the comments, the settings for the geometry package are overwritten by the KOMA option `DIV=last`. Even if so, perhaps the design of the page without the geometry options might be "ok" (as can be seen with `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`. To practically address the problem, the question can be: *how can only the vertical size of the letter page be increased, so the closing and signature and name appear on page one?*

**Screenshots**

Here is page 1

[image]

and here is page 2

[image]

Perhaps it is the (non-visible) footer that makes things hard to keep in one page? I have tried a couple of things to work this around (including suggestions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4472/8272) without success.

How can I force the closing section to stay in page 1 like in the following smudged one page sample?

[image]

Comment: How about `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` or even `\enlargethispage*{\baselineskip}` (which tries to squeeze the text on the page together) before `\close{…}`? You could try different sizes instead of the `\baselineskip`.

Comment: The closing is a quite large block (at least one line of text, greeting, signature) and so it has a tendency to lead to an overfull page and then it goes to the next page. `\enlargethispage{..}`  as suggested by Andreas is normally the way to go. Or reduce the spacing in the text.

Comment: Sorry, but your settings in the linked code are a mess. E.g. package `geometry` is loaded but later on `DIV=last` is used. So every settings by `\geometry` will be overwritten.

Comment: Suggestion: With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you could use `\KOMAoptions{usegeometry}` *before* loading `geometry`. Then replace your `\geometry` settings by `\geometry{verbose,bmargin=1.5cm,includefoot}` and remove the  later `DIV=last` in the argument of `\KOMAoptions` (in custom_invoice_template_el.tex). And maybe you want to change `\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}` to `\@addtoplength[-1.2]{firstfootvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%` in the lco file.

Comment: @Andreas @UlrikeFischer already tried `\enlargethispage{..}` too, does not work as expected. @esdd Thanks for pointing to errors and suggestions. I will test and try to improve.

Comment: @esdd The changes seem to be in the right direction. However, the vertical placement of the top address and the body text is now unaligned and the body text overlaps the info-block (right column).

Comment: Add `usegeometry` to the class options (and remove `\KOMAoptions{usegeometry}` from custom_invoice_template_el.tex.

Comment: @esdd Great -- it looks nice now! Would you care to post an answer? Or, I can do it as well. Note 1: in my previous comment: ... s/vertical/horizontal/ placement... and Note 2: I commented out `\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question and the linked code is a mess. So I will use a different example.

Since KOMA-Script version 3.17 there is an option `usegeometry`. If this option is set, package `typearea` tries to translate all of its options into options of package `geometry`.

So you can add `usegeometry` to the class options. Then you can load `geometry` and change the bottom margin.

```
\documentclass[
  usegeometry
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{bottom=1.5cm,includefoot}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{toaddress}
\opening{Hello,}
\lipsum

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did eventually get what I needed regarding the visual output. I will ask a separate question on how to improve the custom template.