# How to suppress page break in \LaTeX, before enumerate

Tags: page-breaking

There are several ways to suppress page break in \LaTeX, nevertheless, none works for my specific case.

My text contains something like:

```
    Examples
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Example 1.
    \item Example 2.
    ...
    \end{enumerate}
```

How can I avoid "Examples" being in the end of a page while the enumeration starting on the next page? I wouldn't mind, either "Examples" moving in the next page or at least "\item Example 1." staying in the same page with "Examples".

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2644/105447 answer your question? (Also, next time please consider including a full compilable MWE to your question).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487336/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, those two links are interesting to track down. ;-)