# Suppress page-break when a sentence is followed by multi-columns

Tags: page-breaking, multicolumn, multicol

I am trying to suppress page-breaking when a sentence in a single columned text is followed by a multi-column text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

We have the following cases:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First case
\item Second case
\item Third case
\item Fourth case
\item Fifth case
\item Sixth case
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to avoid "We have the following cases:" being the last line of a page while the enumeration starting on the next page? In other words, is it possible that either "We have the following cases:" moves in the next page or some items stay in the same page with "We have the following cases:"?

Replacing

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

by

```
\begin{enumerate}[beginpenalty=10000]
```

did not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Your example would be a lot more useful if it showed the problem you are trying to solve so it could be used to test answers

Comment: Please clarify how this query isn't a duplicate of the [query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708738/5001) you posted 2 days ago?

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `enumerate` *and* `enumitem`; choose one or the other package, *but not both*. (Speaking for myself, I'd use the `enumitem` package.)

Comment: @Mico Actually the query I posted a few days, referred to something more general, and the answer to it solved successfully most cases. However, it did not solve the case where one-column text is followed by two-column text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have modified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `multicols` for such leading text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\rule{1cm}{18cm}


\begin{multicols}{2}[
  We have the following cases:
  ]
\begin{enumerate}
\item First case
\item Second case
\item Third case
\item Fourth case
\item Fifth case
\item Sixth case
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually this works. Thanks.