# Edit all environments created by \newtheorem

Tags: newtheorem

I have created some environments using

```
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{obs}[theo]{Observation}
...
```

and a few more. I'd like to modify all of them adding `\begin{samepage}` before and `\end{samepage}` after each one.

I want something like this:

```
\newtheorem{pretheo}{Theorem}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}{\begin{samepage}\begin{pretheo}}{\end{pretheo}\end{samepage}}
```

but I have too many different environments and I think it's so rough to create two environments for each one.
Is there any direct way to do it with all of them at the same time?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which theorem package do you use? This relates to how `\newtheorem` is defined.

Comment: I suppose it's the package `amsthm`, but then I have `amsmath` and `amssymb` too (Not sure how they work).

Comment: `amsmath` works *with* `amsthm` to control placement of equation numbers and the qed markere, but is neither related otherwise nor necessary for theorems.  `amssymb` is totally separate and unrelated.

Comment: Presumably none of your theorems will be longer than a full page.  But even if they are more than a few lines long, and don't fit on the current page, you may end up with a spacy page if the entire theorem is moved to the next page.  A possible compromise is to use `\needspace{4\baselineskip}` before theorem-class objects.

Answer (score 1):

The following example patches the internal macro of `\newtheorem` (`amsthm` version) to collect the theorem environment name in a list, then redefines those environments at the beginning of document. Here the code execution order is significant, you must firstly patch the internal, then use `\newtheorem`, at last redefine theorems.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% codes added before every occurrances of \newtheorem
\makeatletter
% init a comma-seperated list
\let\thm@list\@empty

% patch \@xnthm, collect theorem env names in \thm@list
% This patch must be used before any use of \newtheorem.
\patchcmd\@xnthm
  {\global\@xp\let}
  {\g@addto@macro\thm@list{,#2}\global\@xp\let}
  {}{\fail}

% patch every theorem env defined before \begin{document}
\AtBeginDocument{
  % strip comma from left
  \def\lstrip@comma,#1\@nil#2{\def#2{#1}}
  \expandafter\lstrip@comma\thm@list\@nil\thm@list
  
  % patch theorem envs
  \@for\@tempa:=\thm@list\do{%
    % backup
    \csletcs{\@tempa @backup}{\@tempa}%
    \csletcs{end\@tempa @backup}{end\@tempa}%
    % redefine
    \edef\temp{%
      \noexpand\renewenvironment{\@tempa}
        {\noexpand\begin{samepage}\noexpand\begin{\@tempa @backup}}
        {\noexpand\end{\@tempa @backup}\noexpand\end{samepage}}%
    }
    \temp
  }
}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{thm}
  content
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}
  content
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}[title]
  content
\end{thm}

\begin{defn}[title]
  content
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

PS: <s>From [document `source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section 17.4, in LaTeX2e `\samepage` is no longer supported. So I'm not sure if it is recommended to use `samepage` environment in 2020. Normally you can use `minipage` environment, see [Unbreakable block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471/).</s>

Update on 2023-05-27: The upcoming LaTeX2e 2023-06-01 release confirms `\samepage` is still supported. The sentence read in `source2e.pdf`

> Since in 2e |\samepage| is no longer supported, ...

is deleted.  Related links

- commit [`ecf19e5a`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/ecf19e5aa0eaea9ad4b98fa066cbbbd148289c01) (Gh1022 (#1023), 2023-03-22)

  - pull request [#1023](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1023) Gh1022
  - issue [#1022](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1022) Resetting \predisplaypenalty in \samepage
- commit [`a7187bb5`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/a7187bb5911000ab67d89cc6da78e9e558479f32) (update some documentation around "samepage"; it is still (reluctantly) supported after all [ci skip], 2023-05-26)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but as I don't understand latex at this level, I just copy-pasted it and it gives some errors before compiling after the line `% redefine` like _"invalid environment command \begin{"_ or _"unexpected close group } after \begin{samepage}"_. Moreover when I compile it doesn't work as expected, instead of keeping all the environment at the same page, I have the _Theorem 3.7_ at the end of the page, and the theorem itself on the following page. And anyway, do you recommend any alternative to the `samepage` environment?

Comment: @Carbonard If my example compiles on your side but the combination of your document + my code compiles with errors, then you need to provide an [MWE] showing your problem. If my example doesn't compile on your side, then you can check your latex installation version info and see if it is too old. I tested on Overleaf.com, and my example compiles from texlive 2014 to 2019. And you can use `minipage` instead of `samepage`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4471/79060.

Comment: It's strange, I'm using overleaf too. I will investigate better how latex works to see if I can adapt this to my code. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ -- I've just reviewed an advance copy of LaTeX News for this year's LaTeX release.  It reports adjustments to `\samepage`, so your note that this is obsolete isn't valid.  I checked with Frank Mittelbach, and he recommended eliminating that comment.  I'd rather you make the correction; if you would like details, send me email.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh... I totally forgot I ever commented `\samepage` in one of my tex-sx answers. Instead of a simple elimination, I applied line through to my previous comment and added description about correct/latest state of `\samepage` with supporting links to the latex2e repo.  Are such changes acceptable to you?

Comment: I knew you could do a better job than I could.  Thanks.  (I'm a fan of `\samepage`, and would hate to lose it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate the infrastructure and define a `\newstheorem` that defines “samepage” theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % not required, but better loading it

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\NewDocumentCommand{\newstheorem}{smomo}{%
  % #1 = optional * for unnumbered theorem
  % #2 = env name
  % #3 = shared counter
  % #4 = label
  % #5 = parent counter
  % define the true environment
  \newenvironment{#2}
    {\par\pagebreak[0]\begin{samepage}\UseName{#2@inner}}
    {\UseName{end#2@inner}\end{samepage}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\newtheorem*{#2@inner}{#4}}%
    {%
     \IfNoValueTF{#5}{%
       % no parent counter
       \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
         % no shared counter
         \newtheorem{#2@inner}{#4}%
       }{% shared counter
         \newtheorem{#2@inner}[#3@inner]{#4}%
       }%
     }{% parent counter
         \newtheorem{#2@inner}{#4}[#5]%
     }%
  }%
}

\newtheorem{theonormal}{Theorem}[section]

\newstheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newstheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}
\newstheorem{obs}[theo]{Observation}

\newstheorem*{foo}{Foo}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{theonormal}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{theonormal}

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{theo}

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{theo}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{theo}


\end{document}
```

In the first two pages I show what normally would happen.

In the following two pages, the “samepage theorem” is used.

The last two pages show that if the statement is very long, `samepage` has no effect, but this should not be a real problem.

[image]