# Page breaks still occur in samepage

Tags: page-breaking, latex-base, samepage

I cannot find any documentation at all on the `samepage` environment (aside from a cryptic comment on p229 of the LaTeX book that "The `\samepage` command still works, but is now of little use", which may or may not be relevant to the environment of the same name).  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4472/16883) and the name of the environment suggests it should keep its contents on the same page, however it doesn't, as this MWE demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-8]

\begin{samepage}
foo

bar
\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```

This breaks the page between the 'foo' and the 'bar'.  Am I misusing the `samepage` environment?  Is it documented anywhere?

This example requires `xelatex` rather than `latex`, but you can see the same in `latex` by adding a third line to the `samepage` environment.

Comment: please provide an example that shows your problem. The code you show makes no output at all. If I add `\end{document}` to get output, it makes a single page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The only error was the missing `\end{document}`.  Use `xelatex` and you'll see the problem.  Question updated accordingly.

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to me, but I think that what it should be on the same page is just the paragraph that doesn't fit, not he whole content like a  minipage. That is, avoid the break the page within a paragraph, but not between two paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

`samepage` makes it infinitely bad to break at every place it could reasonably access,so between lines of  a paragraph (but not single line paragraphs) and at every place latex has control so list items, math displays etc.

Perhaps surprisingly tex has an `\interlinepenalty` primitive to control penalties at line breaks, but nothing to control  the penalty for breaking at `\parskip`.

Latex's new para hooks finally give access to the start and end of a paragraph (see `texdoc ltpara-doc`) so you could add a penalty:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\AddToHook{env/samepage/begin}{%
\AddToHook{para/before}{\nopagebreak}%
\AddToHook{para/after}{\nopagebreak}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-8]

\begin{samepage}
foo

bar

\end{samepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I guess that means my LaTeX distribution (TeX Live 2020/Debian) isn't new enough.

Comment: 2020 is too old, you can of   course add `\nopagebreak explicitly between foo and bar @richard

Comment: @Fran thanks...